# What does p stand for in function names pwrite and pread?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to learn linux api but some function names seem (at least to me) cumbersome.

Could anybody explain to me what does the initial letter p stands for in pwrite/pread?

Comment: it's a prefix for **POSIX** (opposed to _standard C_ library functions fread and fwrite).

Comment: @Adriano `p` stands for *position* as pread reads from a given position. If `p` stands for POSIX then why zillion other POSIX functions don't have that prefix?

Comment: **`p`** is the magic word **please**. If the standard function `func()` returns error, try invoking the `pfunc()` variant. :P

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6t6k9tehlv4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am only guessing, but since `pread()`and `pwrite()` read or write at a specified *position* in the file, I would assume that the "p" stands for "positional", as in "positional read".

Both `read()` and `pread()` are part of the POSIX standard (see e.g. http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/pread/), therefore I don't think that "p" stands for "POSIX".

But perhaps this is completely wrong!

Comment: Make that p "positional", and I for one will fully agree :)

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Thanks for the suggestion, that sounds better!

Comment: +1 I **always** thought "p" stands for POSIX to distinguish them from their "standard" counterparts (like for pthreads...) but this sounds much better!!!

Comment: @meaning-matters: Yes, and perror() is positional error() :-) - OP is probably totally confused now!

Comment: POSIX.1-2001 also defines `readv()` and `writev()` that read and write one or more I/O vectors (scatter/gather); I read that `v` as *vector*. Linux and some BSDs also provide `preadv()` and `pwritev()`, which work like you'd expect: read and write one or more I/O vectors starting at a specific position (*positional read vectors*, *positional write vectors*). This is why I've never associated the `p` prefix with POSIX. For further details, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/writev.2.html

Comment: pthread_create    prefix p ?

Comment: @RioWing: pthread stands indeed for “POSIX thread”

Answer (score 1):

p in pread and pwrite refers to [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

The two differences of "p" variant as opposed to read and write are:

- The "p" variants take offset to read from, so they are independent of the current file pointer. That makes it easier to read/write from multiple threads concurrently.
- The "p" variants only work on seekable files (i.e. real files, not pipes, sockets or devices).

Comment: And provide a reference.

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). [`pread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pread.html). [`pwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html).

Comment: The `pread()` function shall be equivalent to `read()`, except that it
shall read from a given position in the file without changing the file pointer.
The first three arguments to `pread()` are the same as `read()` with the
addition of a fourth argument offset for the desired position inside the file.
An attempt to perform a `pread()` on a file that is incapable of seeking
shall result in an error.

Comment: The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()`, except that it writes into a given position and does not change the file offset (regardless of
whether **O_APPEND** is set). The first three arguments to `pwrite()` are the
same as `write()` with the addition of a fourth argument offset for the desired
position inside the file. An attempt to perform a `pwrite()` on a file that is
incapable of seeking shall result in an error.